# Angular CORS , C# server side failing

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I am using making a http post call to a C# WEB API and resulting in "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

WEB API - StartUp.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",builder => 
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials() );
              });

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ReadOnlyJsonContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, WhiteBoxDBContext context)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

//Controller

```
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("ValidateUser")]
     [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
     public ValidateUser<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Error:-

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

Not sure what I have omitted but this should work....

Comment: Have you try to enable cors on all the controller not this specific action ? Oh, and this can be not the exact error i think, in some case, you have this error but it's not a cors error, is a server error non catch or other. Try to debug your api code i think or the return you have. Check Network Dev tool to see if you have an error in the request

Comment: @Paul - will try that now...

Comment: How do you handle exceptions ? Do you have any exception handling filter or middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddCors();
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

// Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, WhiteBoxDBContext context)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

//Controller

```
[HttpPost]
     [Route("ValidateUser")]
     public ValidateUser<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Comment: be sure your chrome CORS extension should be off

Answer (score 0):

1) Install package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

2) Open the webapiconfig. cs file and add the following line in Register() method(just before routes are added):

```
config.EnableCors();
```

3) decorate your controller/action methods(wherever applicable) with below line:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://www.myclientsite.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController{   .......   }
```

Comment: refer to link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api for more details